# How to read SQL queries from a properties file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I have a legacy spring mvc application which is using spring jdbc as ORM. Now I wanted to use spring boot and instead of mvc I will be converting it in to RestAPI. I have problem with database query part. Using propertyplaceholder xml confi the external sql query properties file is configured in the old application. Using Spring boot and latest annotation methods how can I configure this. My understanding is

1. Place the query properties file in **src/main/resources** directory
2. In DAO create property name same as the key ( name ) of the sql.
3. create getter and setter for the key property

Is this is the right approach ? if yes if I use this how I will get the query in my DAO class ?. If not what is the best method.

Comment: Why do you want to put the SQL in a property file?

Comment: few are large queries. Since it is an already exisiting application I wanted to use it as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting this question I didn't get much response. So I did some work from my side and the fixed it same way as I mentioned in the question. I didn't find any other method.

First a java class **ApplicationPropertyConfig** for PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer . Property source file is my sql properties file.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:appSql.properties")
public class ApplicationPropertyConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
```

}

**appSql.properties**

```
selectallemployees=select * from employee;
```

created another class with name **ApplicationSQLWrapper.java** which is annotated with @Component. This contains the property name same as the sql properties key with @value annotation.

```
@Component
public class ApplicationSQLWrapper{ 
    
    @Value("${selectallemployees}")
    private String selectallemployees;

//getter and setter
```

This SQL's  can be accessed from DAO class by creating an Object of the Component class.

Comment: can you please show  your DAO class and how you implementing this sql query? Im trying to achieve same thing

Comment: Create getter and setter for each property in ApplicationSQLWrapper.java and create an object (autowired) of SQLWrapper  in DAO and access the query using getter.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good approach but you can do it in several ways and I am always approaching to use JPA when you work with database and spring boot

### application.yml

```
 emp:
    eid: "select eid from employee"
    name: "select ename from employee"
```

create a class for Employee under the model package

```
 @ConfigurationProperties("emp")
  @Getter
  @Setter
  public class Employee
 {
      private List<Integer> eid;
      private List<String> ename;
 }
```

create a bean instance for Employee under the config package

```
@Configuration
public class Config
{
     @Bean
     public Employee getEmployee()
    {
         return new Employee();
    }
}
```

then you can call Employee instance whenever you need in your project

```
@RestController
public class EmpController
{
    @Autowired
    Employee emp;
}
```

Comment: In my case I have 1200 SQL queries and in that most of them are very complex queries. There is no specific entity class and it is a legacy monolithic application.

Comment: If you don't have specific tables for each entity then go with native queries otherwise you have to face struggles when creating relationship, Composite class kind of stuff

Comment: Also the  exisitng code uses springJDBC. Replacing that with Spring data jdbc  or spring data jpa will be a tedious job.